# How to get date before last date in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, onbeforeunload

How to get date before last date in mysql if i have table below

```
Date    customerID
04/01/2016  3
04/01/2016  3
08/01/2016  3
08/01/2016  3
11/01/2016  3
```

for this customerID the output would be

```
last Date 11/01/2016
date before last 08/01/2016
```

Comment: You really want the output in 2 rows?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to select the second last row in your record you can use the `LIMIT` function in mysql. You can read more about [limit here.](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_limit.asp)

I suggest to try this solution:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1, 1
```

And here another link for the example [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/104560/how-to-select-second-last-row-from-table)

Hope it helps.

Comment: thks , but if customer make something more that once in the same day Limit wont work

Comment: @RomaChernilovsky, Please clarify your question so we can suggest more accurate solution, because in the question above, you only want to select the second last record and nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

On MySQL 8+, `ROW_NUMBER` works nicely here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE CustomerID = 3
)

SELECT 'last date' AS label, Date FROM cte WHERE rn = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'date before last', Date FROM cte WHERE rn = 2
ORDER BY Date DESC;
```

Comment: thks , but if customer make something more that once in the same day , how do you know which rnk to refer him ?